# Conditional expectation interpretation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{4\}$ and $X$ be a random variable.

Then $E(E(X|\{A,B\}))$ has any meaning? How should I interpret this? I mean I condition on a family of sets that is NOT sigma algebra but just 2 disjoint events.

Comment: "Then $E(E(X|\{A,B\}))$ has any meaning?" No. What is your source?

Comment: 17th page of this pdf: https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/sites/gsb/files/working-papers/Yizhou%20Xiao%20paper2.pdf

Comment: F^i is any partition of sample space, it doesnt have to be sigma algebra

Comment: According to author, it seems that $E(E(X|\{A,B\}))=P(A)E(X|A)+P(B)E(X|B)=EX$

Comment: This probably amounts to defining $E(X|F)$ as $E(X|\sigma(F))$, where $\sigma(F)$ denotes the smallest sigma-algebra containing $F$.

Comment: So basically it should be $E(E(X|\sigma(\{A,B\})))=P(A)E(X|A)+P(B)E(X|B)=EX$   Thanks!